# Where does openssl.cnf live in Windows?

Tags: wordpress, openssl

Apparently, Local WP uses the `openssl.cnf` file `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf`, and the Windows version might be found at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL/openssl.cnf`.

The folder `C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL\` doesn't exist on my PC.

How does it get there?

Is Local WP on Windows meant to create it?

Does OpenSSL need to be manually installed and configured to work with Local WP on Windows?

My local MainWP produces a 500 error for `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and the error log says:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: openssl_pkey_get_details(): Argument #1 ($key) must be of type OpenSSLAsymmetricKey, bool given in C:\Users\Steve\Local Sites\mainwp\app\public\wp-content\plugins\mainwp\class\class-mainwp-manage-sites-view.php:1550
```

I am unsure if this MainWP error is because Local WP does not have OpenSSL set up.

MainWP has a setting to locate the `openssl.cnf` file, if this setting were set properly, the 500 error might disappear.

Comment: In Windows, typically the openssl.cnf file can be found in the `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\` directory, if its the case, then the setting should be set `OPENSSL_CONF=C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg`. However, the path to the file may vary depending on how OpenSSL was installed on your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalWP saves the file as `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Local\resources\extraResources\lightning-services\php-8.1.9+8\bin\win32\extras\ssl\openssl.cnf` on Windows, [[source]](https://community.localwp.com/t/where-does-openssl-cnf-live-in-windows/35908/18?u=s.doig)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had OpenSSL installed through Git, so I opened git bash and ran `which openssl` (which is similar to `where openssl` in Windows). This gave me a path like `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\`.

From there, I opened up CMD in the `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64` folder (since I didn't think the configuration file would be in the `bin` folder) and ran `dir /s /b openssl.cnf`, which recursively searches that folder and children for the specified openssl.cnf file (I usually find `dir` faster/more thorough than the regular Windows search, but that's just me). This gave me the path `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\ssl\openssl.cnf`. I doubt it will be the same path for you, but you can follow this process to narrow down where the config file likely is.